# How to increase width of labels?

Tags: apexcharts

I need to increase width of displayed text labels. I can't find proper parameter that affected to it.

I suppose that it should be something here:

```
labels: {
    style: {
       fontSize: '12px',
           },
       rotate: -5,
       // it should be something here
     },
```

I tried:

```
minWidth: 430,
minWidth: 610
```

but it does not do any affect.

Could anybody help me? I need to display full label text.

https://jsfiddle.net/swLpynua/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum width for a y-axis label is set to `160px`

You may try changing that

```js
yaxis: {
  labels: {
     maxWidth: 250
  }
}
```